# Выскакивает ошибка: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". Подскажите как исправить?

Tags: javascript, frontend, консоль, ecmascript-6

Есть 2 файла. В один из файлов необходимо импортировать другой. Использую ES6.

Файл extra.js.

```
export function func() {
    console.log('i am func');
}
```

Файл index.js.

```
import func from './extra';
func();
```

Ошибка в консоли: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: В каком браузере проверяли? Как подключали js модуль в html?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

И ещё надо либо

> ```
> export function func() {
> ```

```
export default function func() {
```

либо

> ```
> import func from './extra';
> ```

```
import {func} from './extra';
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/246009)

Comment: @Sublihim, почему не является?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Sublihim, я в курсе, что написано в справке. Почему ты утверждаешь, что этот ответ - не ответ?

Comment: Ну вот, ещё и минусатор какой-то набрёл (((